# Is it a relative clause?

Tags: meaning, sentence

> At last summer’s Farnborough Air Show, the chief executive of Boeing, Dennis Muilenburg, was so upbeat about the American planemaker’s prospects **he set off alarm bells among aerospace analysts**.

Is it a relative clause to modify prospect? Is it wrong to use 'he' here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not a relative clause.  "... he set off ..." is a *that*-clause (though the "that" is not explicit) going with the adjective "upbeat".  "He was so upbeat that he set off alarm bells."
Or rather, filling things out, the *that*-clause goes with the adjective clause "upbeat about the American planemaker’s prospects" and is part of the comparative construction that begins with "so".

"He" is fine.

Comment: Right. It appears as the `S` part of the _so upbeat ... that `S`_ construction: _so happy that he danced, so tired that I fell asleep_, etc. _So_ means 'to such an extent' and the _that_ clause describes the extent and its result.